# How to automount a gvfs file system on logon

Tags: nautilus, samba, remote-access, remote, gvfs

I configured a remote folder in nautilus. I always need this remote folder, so I created a symbolic link to it in my home folder: `ln -s ~/.gvfs/remote_folder ~/remote_folder`.

Though, when I first boot the computer this folder is not mounted, and I have to access it through nautilus in order to have it available in `~/remote_folder`.

What should I do to have this folder mounted on log on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Shell

You could use the `mount` command in a start up script and put that in the **Startup Application Preferences**. `mount` is perfectly capable of mounting remote file systems (if you provided it with the right options and all necessary packages installed).

An alternative to mount in your startup script is [gvfs-mount](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gvfs-bin) [image: Install gvfs-bin]. You can mount nautilus-type URIs with that - just like nautilus does. It is installed by default on most Ubuntu systems.
Example usage:

```
gvfs-mount 'ftp://user@www.your-server.com/folder'
```

Adding the `-u` option unmounts the argument, `-l` lists all mounted file systems, `--help` gives you more options.

Finally the file `/etc/fstab` is usually used to mount file systems statically. If your remote server is reliable you might want to [take a look at fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). It will slow down your boot time drastically if the server is slow or offline, but it has the advantage of making the file system available quite soon (before gnome or X are even loaded, e.g. for use in scripts). For more information you can type `man fstab`.

### GUI way

Check out [Gigolo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gigolo) [image: Install gigolo]. It has the capability of auto-mounting a bookmark, whenever the bookmarked filesystem is present.

```
sudo apt-get install gigolo   # or use the install link above
```

Run `gigolo`. There is an option in the preferences that puts it into autostart and another to activate the tray icon. Check both. Then add your bookmark.

[image: Gigolo used to automount]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was exactly looking forward to find this last more user-friendly and resource-consuming solution. Though, I advise the other people that eventualy have this question to read all the answers and ponder well on which suits their needs better.

Comment: small typo: /etc/fsatab  should be /etc/fstab

Answer (score 4):

First install gvfs-bin package:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin
```

then mount URI you need. For example:

```
gvfs-mount 'archive://file%253A%252F%252F%252Ftmp%252Ftest.tar/'
```

to test it:

```
ls -la ~/.gvfs/test.tar/
```

to unmount it, just call:

```
gvfs-mount -u 'archive://file%253A%252F%252F%252Ftmp%252Ftest.tar/'
```

Note, that there is no man pages. for this package. To learn more, list available binaries via:

```
dpkg -L gvfs-bin
```

and then use --help option, for example:

```
gvfs-mount --help
```

Comment: Worth noting that in later versions the mounted directory would end up in `/run/user/<uid>/gvfs/test.tar/`.  See [How to access gvfs mounts from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232497)

Answer (score 2):

I usually do permanent mounts through fstab. You have to enter something like

```
//servername/folder HOME/remote_server cifs username=XXXX,password=YYYY 0 0
```

in your `/etc/fstab`. Since you haven't said anything about what kind of remote partition I gave an example of `samba share`

See:

- [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)
- [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

The second option may be using [autofs](http://autofs.org), see [the Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) for help.

EDIT: Thank you @con-f-use for reminding me this one. You can add bookmarks from nautilus only. Go to **File > Connect to Server...** on nautilus and you will be presented with dialogue window where you have the option to add a bookmark of desired name. Just check the add bookmark option and enter the bookmark name. But I think it starts the mounting only after you click the bookmark unlike gigolo.

[image]

Comment: That has the disadvantage of delaying your systems boot, when the remote server is not reachable (internet down, sever maintainace etc.)

Comment: You can put the credentials in a separate file that only root can read (often non root users can read /etc/fstab and thus see userid/passwords stored there). Use credentials=/root/remove_server.credentials where that file has two lines in it,

username=userid
password=userids-password

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `/etc/fstab` (e.g. bad on multi-user PCs, no root access) or don't want to save your user password to a text file in your home folder (e.g. no encrypted file system) using `gvfs-mount smb://$SERVERIP/$SHARE < ~/.smbcredentials_gvfs`,

run this shell script on startup (or whenever you want):

```
#!/bin/bash
USERID=`id -u $USER`; # Needed in 14.04
SHARE=exampleshare # Example
SERVERIP=192.168.2.101 # Example
nautilus smb://$SERVERIP/$SHARE & # Mount the share using nautilus. You need to have your password saved permanently
rm ~/network_$SHARE # prepare symbolic link (Example)
ln -sf /run/user/$USERID/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=$SERVERIP\,share\=$SHARE ~/network_$SHARE # Directory in Ubuntu 14.04
sleep 2 # Nautilus needs some time to mount. Killing nautilus without waiting time does not mount the share
pkill nautilus
```

This mounts the shares you want and uses the nautilus (or Ubuntu) password saving mechanism (does not work in SSH though).

Comment: Of all the answers this is the only one actually addressing the question.