# how to make startup application to open the folder or inode/directory after booting?

Tags: mouse, 12.04, startup

[image]

I think it will be awesome if after login the folder that locate not at the same localhost / can open it self like and application as skype and others. do we can make it because if this one works for it , it will help others people too that save musics and other file under the /home folder or the like me , i do need to click other partitions to listen songs and movie and other what i want is just single click when i do login. the partitions / folder / inode was open so i can simply click the Play button at the rhythmbox and click next just to watch the next edition of serial movies ^^ 
here the photos, i need this partition / hard disk to open during start-up "almacén hard disk. thx

[image]

for daniel request .

```
santos@santos:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  68.6G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 130.9G  0 part /media/almacén
├─sda5   8:5    0  46.6G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   2.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7   8:7    0  46.6G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0   3.1G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: to  clarify your question do you just want to mount all your hard disks on start-up so you can use them immediately like you would use your normal / filesystem (this can be done in the background without anything popping up on your screen). 
Or do you want to mount the filesystem and show it's content in a file manager window right on start-up?

Comment: @Daniel only one harddisk partition .. where there is music and video and other file .. so i dont need to mount it to play musics .

Comment: please mount your hard drive and post the output the lsblk command into your question. I will write an answer as soon as I'm home (cell phone right now)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [How to automount a gvfs file system on logon?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56428/how-to-automount-a-gvfs-file-system-on-logon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to edit your /etc/fstab file in order too mount the external hard drive partition on boot.
To do this type the following:

You need to get the UUID of your external hdd, type:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda4
```

copy the line UUID="some-long-number"

now unmount the disk and make a folder to mount it in the future:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda4
```

then:

```
sudo mkdir /media/almacén
```

now type:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and go to the end of the page using your arrow keys.

now copy&paste the following

```
#external hard drive almacén was on /dev/sda4 at the time of writing.
UUID=some-long-number  /media/almacén       auto        defaults        0     2
```

where UUID=some-long-number is the UUID you got from the 'blkid' command earlier
 (BUT WITHOUT THE " " )

Shutdown your computer, plug the external hdd back in and restart.
Your drive partition 'almacén' should now be mounted on '/media/almacén' on login.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to create an autostart folder, but you can do it this way:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit /home/yourUser/.config/autostart/nameYourShortcut.desktop --create-new
```

For the command in your new short cut that will be launched at startup use:

```
nautilus /the/directory/path/here
```

Comment: the problem with this is you'd still have to mount the device /dev/sda4 to /media/almacen first (or in fact any other location) in order to use it with the nautilus command or else the /path/to/directory won't be accesible.

Answer (score -1):

From **Startup Applications**, Create a new startup entry in which enter command as

```
bash -c 'nautilus "/path/to/folder"'
```