# Remove Owncloud login from file system / Nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, remote, gvfs

At some point, I've added a remote mount to a Owncloud installation. I've since reinstalled Owncloud, so the original remote has the wrong login details. Every time I login to my computer, whatever is mounting the remote tries to login to Owncloud with the original password, but fails to do so. **However, Owncloud is working perfectly well. It syncs succesfully and has no problems logging in. The problem relates only to whatever remote mount is visible in Nautilus.**

I have no idea what I used to mount the remote and can't figure out how to edit or remove the mount.

The remote shows up in my Nautilus menu (pic below), but is not listed with `df`, presumably because it is not mounted. Nautilus can't edit the mount and trying to mount it by clicking just shows a text box telling me that the login details are wrong.

[image: Screenshot of Nautilus]

I can see the remote with `gvfs-mount -l`, but I can't figure out where the configs for the mounts are stored and how to edit them.

```
Volume(0): XXX@XXXX.com
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGoa)
```

The contents of my `.gvfs`-folder and `/run/user/USER/gvfs` are empty. The remote is not mounted in my `fstab`.

How do I edit and/or permanently remove the remote mount?

Below is the requested content of my /$HOME/.local/share/data/ownCloud/owncloud.cfg. I have sanitized it slightly by replacing my username with "usename", the actual domain with "domain.com" and removed the certificate. I have also translated the actual folder names to English.

```
[General]
crashReporter=true
monoIcons=true
newBigFolderSizeLimit=500
optionalDesktopNotifications=true
useNewBigFolderSizeLimit=true

[Accounts]
0\Folders\1\ignoreHiddenFiles=true
0\Folders\1\localPath=/home/username/Documents/
0\Folders\1\paused=false
0\Folders\1\targetPath=/Documents
0\Folders\2\ignoreHiddenFiles=true
0\Folders\2\localPath=/home/username/Documents/
0\Folders\2\paused=false
0\Folders\2\targetPath=/Pictures
0\authType=http
0\http_certificatePasswd=
0\http_certificatePath=
0\http_user=username
0\serverVersion=9.1.3.1
0\url=https://domain.com
0\user=username
version=2

[ActivityListHeader]
geometry=@ByteArray(\0\0\0\xff\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\b\x1b\0\0\0\x5\x1\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x64\xff\xff\xff\xff\0\0\0\x81\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x5\0\0\0\x96\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\x2\xdc\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\x3\xe1\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x64\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\0\0\0\x3\xe8\0)

[BWLimit]
downloadLimit=80
uploadLimit=10
useDownloadLimit=0
useUploadLimit=0

[Settings]
geometry="@ByteArray(\x1\xd9\xd0\xcb\0\x2\0\0\0\0\x1+\0\0\0\x93\0\0\x6\x46\0\0\x3q\0\0\x1,\0\0\0\xaf\0\0\x6\x45\0\0\x3p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\x80)"

[ownCloud]
General\CaCertificates="[Certificate removed]"
authType=http
http_certificatePasswd=
http_certificatePath=
http_user=username
url=https://domain.com
user=usename
```

Comment: Anything in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`?

Comment: Nothing relevant. Those wouldn't try an automount either, would they?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the ouput of `cat $HOME/.local/share/data/ownCloud/owncloud.cfg` or provide a pastebin link to it. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the content of ` /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf.` Best guess at this point. For other ideas see [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs)

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56428/how-to-automount-a-gvfs-file-system-on-logon?rq=1) might possibly help you remember what you did originally. That would be very useful to know in order to reverse the process.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. There is no /etc/davfs2/ or anything similar. My original post lists the most probable options for mounting gvfs, which is why I am at loss.

Comment: Agreed. gvfs can use numerous [backends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gvfs-backends) which makes this a bit like looking for a needle in a haystack. Have you considered using `grep` to find the string you get from `gvfs-mount -l` for instance the unsanitized version of `XXX@XXXX.com` or perhaps even `GProxyVolumeMonitorGoa`

Comment: `gvfs-mount --monitor` might also provide some clues as to what's going on.

Comment: Edited answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus Version 3.18 introduced integration with Google Drive and GOA (gnome-online-accounts) settings.

If you simply want to remove a GOA, Launch Online Accounts, select the account you wish to remove on the left and Click the Remove Account button in the lower-left corner of the window as shown below:

[image: GOA]

An alternative approach would be to use apt to purge the package entirely but that seems much like taking a sledgehammer to a screw.

If you want to **repair** your connection, read on.

By default, owncloudcmd reads the client configuration in `$HOME/.local/share/data/ownCloud` and uses the credentials of the GUI synchronization client. If no client is configured, or if you choose to use a different user to synchronize, you can specify the user password setting with the usual URL pattern. For example:

`$ owncloudcmd / https://carla:secret@server/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/`

You can open the Owncloud Sync client that has failed to connect.

[image: errorconnecting]

A right click on the icon will open the following menu.

[image: menu]

Choose Settings and Click Modify Account or Accounts depending on your version of the client on the screen similar to what is shown below.

[image: modify account]

You should be able to modify account credentials or worst case,  remove and re-add the account as necessary

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/accounts-remove.html.en

https://owncloud.com/latest-gnome-ships-with-owncloud-support/

https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/1.8/navigating.html

https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.1/navigating.html

Comment: Thanks, but you did not answer the question that was asked but some completely different question. Deleting your answer would probably be the best solution.

Comment: @krax From your question It seemed clear to me that you needed to edit the credentials to successfully mount the remote store. You have my apologies if you meant something different. Be that as it may, Just because this isn't the answer you wanted doesn't mean it's not accurate.  I suggest that you review [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) (at least the final paragraph). I believe this answer has value to future users, is accurate and as such I will not be deleting it. In future please be so kind as to respond to requests for further information by [edit]ing your post.

Comment: I think you are using the word "mount" very liberally. Owncloud doesn't mount anything by itself, so your solution would be to general sync problems -- which I don't have. My Owncloud works perfectly. But as described in my problem, I have a remote file system mount shown in Nautilus that is trying to access my Owncloud unsuccesfully. Your suggested solution does not relate to that problem. The difference seems unclear, so I will clarify my question. I have added the contents of the file you requested. Sorry, I didn't notice the request at first.

Comment: @krax You have my apologies for using **mount** as you did in your question if for some reason that offends you, review yoru own post. Comments on your post should show up in your inbox. You can also set notification preferences on [your profile page](http://askubuntu.com/users/182719/krax) Under Edit Profile and Settings - >Preferences It is my sincere hope that this information may help you .

Comment: I simply meant that you use the word in a different sense than it is usually used. I use it in my post because I mean that Nautilus is trying to mount the filesystem remotely. Your comment (and answer to my question) seems to imply that it is Owncloud that is trying to mount the folder, which is to the best of my knowledge, false. As far as I know, Owncloud doesn't mount anything. I will gladly revise my position if I am mistaken.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by removing online accounts and adding them again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad I was able to help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your ~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf to remove WebDAV link

Comment: Please note that your answer is not for OP alone bu also for other site visitors so please tell us how this should be done!